# Qbs >= 1.8 new property override syntax fails for modules

Tags: qbs

I have an app with product `myproduct`, depending on custom module `mymodule`:

```
// myproduct.qbs
Product {
    name: "myproduct"
    Depends { name: "mymodule" }
}

// mymodule.qbs
Module {
   name: "mymodule"
   property string value: ""
   validate: { if (value == "") throw "mymodule.value is not set!" }
}
```

With Qbs 1.7 and lower I could set this property externally with syntax:

```
qbs ... mymodule.value:"somevalue"
```

and it worked as expected. With qbs 1.8 and newer, this fails with error:

```
Property override key 'mymodule.value' not understood.
Please use one of the following:
    projects.<project-name>.<property-name>:value
    products.<product-name>.<property-name>:value
    modules.<module-name>.<property-name>:value
    products.<product-name>.<module-name>.<property-name>:value
```

But neither of those work (property value is left unchanged):

```
qbs ... modules.mymodule.value:"somevalue"
qbs ... products.myproduct.mymodule.value:"somevalue"
```

What am I missing? Or is this a qbs bug?

P.S. it works as expected with `project.someproperty:"..."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example works fine for me. I suggest you file a bug report at bugreports.qt.io and attach a *complete* example project. We can then figure out what's the problem there.

Comment: can you please specify which version of qbs are you using?

Comment: Both the current 1.9 and master branches.

Comment: well, seems there was in fact a bug. In 1.9 it surely works fine.